# How do I add a custom monitoring feature in my Spark application?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, monitoring, bigdata

I am developing a Spark application. The application takes data from Kafka queue and processes that data. After processing it stores data in Hbase table.

Now I want to monitor some of the performance attributed such as,

1. Total count of input and output records.(Not all records will be persisted to Hbase, some of the data may be filtered out in processing)
2. Average processing time per message
3. Average time taken to persist the messages.

I need to collect this information and send it to a different Kafka queue for monitoring.

Considering that the monitoring should not incur a significant delay in the processing.

Please suggest some ideas for this.

Thanks.

Comment: You can always use Spark accumulators although you need to realize that accumulators don't have an `only once` semantic

Comment: I used accumulators but my mentor says they will cause a delay. He is asking to find out some inbuilt functionality of Spark for this purpose. I am not sure other than accumulators what else can be used.

Comment: Delays ? What delays ? And accumulators are built-in.

Comment: So the thing is according to him, all the accumulators will send data to driver node which will cause a heavy traffic. He wants to avoid that. Is there a way to control the sending of data after say 10 batches. Currently I am sending data for each batch.

Comment: He's right about the fact it will come back to the driver. I don't know enough about Kafka to answer this question, I actually haven't used Spark in a streaming context

Comment: However, how big are the accumulators going to be anyway ? They are just aggregates and stats on your data, how can that be so big it could harm performance ?

Comment: That's true. That's what I think. Thanks, though.

Comment: If that's not too hard for you to make an attempt, go ahead and try the accumulators. Your mentor has more context than me so they might be right about the performance impact, but from where I stand it sounds dubious that it could be that expensive. Good luck :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118178/discussion-between-dhruven1600-and-dici).